# Future<void>, async, await, then, catchError in Flutter/Dart

Tags: asynchronous, flutter, dart, async-await

What is the difference between:

**Future<void>, async, await, then, catchError**

```
Future<void> copyToClipboard(BuildContext context, String text) async {
  await Clipboard.setData(ClipboardData(text: text))
      .then((_) => showSnackBar(context, 'Copied to clipboard'))
      .catchError((Object error) => showSnackBar(context, 'Error $error'));
}
```

**void, async, await, then, catchError**

```
void copyToClipboard(BuildContext context, String text) async {
  await Clipboard.setData(ClipboardData(text: text))
      .then((_) => showSnackBar(context, 'Copied to clipboard'))
      .catchError((Object error) => showSnackBar(context, 'Error $error'));
}
```

**void, then, catchError**

```
void copyToClipboard(BuildContext context, String text) {
  Clipboard.setData(ClipboardData(text: text))
      .then((_) => showSnackBar(context, 'Copied to clipboard'))
      .catchError((Object error) => showSnackBar(context, 'Error $error'));
}
```

All methods work. If I'm using `then` and `catchError`, do I still need to wrap the code in an `async` function?

Which is the recommended way?

Comment: you use `async` only when `await` is used in function body - and in that case `async` function shouldn't return `void` as there is no way to check when the function completes - you should return a `Future` (even if its `Future<void>`)

Comment: and when using `async` / `await` stuff there is a little need for using Future` API - `then()` and `catchError()` - for more read https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await and https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/futures-error-handling

Answer (score 3):

First of, the concept of `async/await` and `then` is basically the same. Many people say that `async/await` is the more elegant way to deal with Promises (because it looks more structured). What both ideas do is: "Do something and once it is done, do something else".

Regarding `Future<void> copyToClipboard(BuildContext context, String text) async {...}`:
Here you are returning a Promise from your function. Meaning, that you can call the function from somewhere else with

```
await copyToClipboard(context,"Text"); 
print("Done");
```

You can, however also return the Promise itself (and then handle it wherever you call that function):

```
Future<void> copyToClipboard(BuildContext context, String text) async {
  return Clipboard.setData(ClipboardData(text: text));    
}
void somewhereElse() async{
 await copyToClipboard(context,"Text"); // (1)
 print("Copied"); //Happens after (1)
}
```

So if you are using `then`, you will put the following instructions into the corresponding function called by it (as seen in your 3rd snippet). Solving the 2nd snippet with async would looke like this:

```
void copyToClipboard(BuildContext context, String text) async {
  await Clipboard.setData(ClipboardData(text: text));// (1)
  showSnackBar(context, 'Copied to clipboard')); // (2) This will only be called when (1) has completed
}
```

If this instruction throws an error, you can wrap it into a try/catch block:

```
void copyToClipboard(BuildContext context, String text) async {
  try{
      await Clipboard.setData(ClipboardData(text: text));// (1)
      showSnackBar(context, 'Copied to clipboard')); // (2) This will only be called when (1) has completed
  }catch (error) {
     print(error.message);
  }
}
```

If you prefer then/wait or async/await is up to you. I would recommend async/await. Keep in mind that when using async/await, you need to put the `async` keyword into the signature of the function, so functions calling this function are aware, that calling it may take a while and wait for it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In your latest code sample, shouldn't the async function return `Future<void>` instead of `void`?

Comment: Nope, because you are not returning anything. when you have a future as the return type, you also need to return a future, as seen in the 2nd block.