# Flutter - redirect to new screen using .then(), Provider.of(), and Navigator

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, flutter-navigation

I have a button which on initial click/tap/touch, it POST to API and return true or false based on auth.

> ```
> onPressed: ()=>{
> Provider.of<Login>(context, listen: false).login()
> .then((value) => {
>   if(value == true)
>     Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/home')
>   }),
> },
> ```

> ```
> Future<bool> login() async {
>     try{
>       var payload = jsonEncode({
>         'email': usrname,
>         'password': pswd
>       });
>       Map<String,dynamic> response = await fetch.post(url, body:payload, headers: {
>         'Accept':'application/json',
>         'content-type': 'application/json'
>       })
>       .then((value) => jsonDecode(value.body));
>       if(response['token'] != ''){
>         return true;
>       }
>     }
>     catch(e){
>       errorMsg = e.toString();
>       notifyListeners();
>       return false;
>     }
>     return false;
>   }
> ```

On successful authentication, it doesn't redirect to new screen as intended. Am I missing something or my logic is flawed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`await` is meant to interrupt the process flow until the `async` method has finished. `then` however does not interrupt the process flow (meaning the next instructions will be executed) but enables you to run code when the async method is finished.

In your code :

The issue is about your `login` method. You used an `await` with a `then`, you don't need to use both at the same time.

```
Future<bool> login() async {
    try{
      var payload = jsonEncode({
        'email': usrname,
        'password': pswd
      });
      Map<String,dynamic> response = await fetch.post(url, body:payload, headers: {
        'Accept':'application/json',
        'content-type': 'application/json'
      });
      var decodedResponse = jsonDecode(response.body);
      if(decodedResponse['token'] != ''){
        return true;
      }
    }
    catch(e){
      errorMsg = e.toString();
      notifyListeners();
      return false;
    }
    return false;
  }
```

You can find more examples in SO issues :

- [Async/Await/then in Dart/Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54515186/async-await-then-in-dart-flutter)
- [Future<void>, async, await, then, catchError in Flutter/Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60575776/futurevoid-async-await-then-catcherror-in-flutter-dart)

Comment: This is the ticket! I guess habit from Javascript isn't that easily being forgotten. Thanks a lot!